# TargetNullValue not working in ListView in Xamarin app

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to display some text -- or an image -- if there's no data for my `ListView` to display in my Xamarin Forms 5 app but I can't get it to work.

Here's what my `ListView` looks like:

```
<ListView
   x:Name="CustomersList"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Customers, TargetNullValue='No customers!'}"
   BackgroundColor="Transparent">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <TextCell
                 Text="{Binding FullName}"
                 TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryDark}"
                 Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=CustomersList}, Path=BindingContext.CustomerSelectedCommand}"
                 CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The source for the `ListView` is set as follows in my ViewModel

```
ObservableRangeCollection<CustomerModel> customers;
public ObservableRangeCollection<CustomerModel> Customers
{
   get => customers;
   set
   {
      if (customers == value)
         return;

      customers = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

If my API call returns nothing, I do a `Customers = null;`

When I use `TargetNullValue` as shown above, I acutally get errors where I bind the `TextCell` to `FullName`. It shows:

> 'FullName' property not found on 'N', target property:
> 'Xamarin.Forms.TextCell.Text'

It then repeats this error message for every character in `No Customers!`.

I then tried using `FallbackValue`. This time I don't get an error but it simply doesn't show the "No Customers!" message.

How do I handle a `ListView` having no data to show? At the very least, I'd like to show some simple text message but it would be even better to show something nicer, maybe an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok to switch from `ListView` to `CollectionView`, you can use the built-in `CollectionView.EmptyView`:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"
                EmptyView="No customers!" ... />
```

With the same `EmptyView` you can define whatever view:

```
<CollectionView>
    <CollectionView.EmptyView>
        <ContentView>
           <image ... /> 
        </ContentView>
    </CollectionView.EmptyView>
</CollectionView>
```

Docs: [CollectionView EmptyView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/emptyview#display-a-string-when-data-is-unavailable)

Comment: Yes, I've switched to `CollectionView` and I like the flexibility I get from this control. Thanks.